# What is a simple C or C++ TCP server and client example?

Tags: c++, tcp, client-server

I need to quickly implement a very small C or C++ TCP server/client solution. This is simply to transfer literally an array of bytes from one computer to another - doesn't need to be scalable / over-complicated. The simpler the better. Quick and dirty if you can.

I tried to use the code from this tutorial, but I couldn't get it to build using g++ in Linux: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

If possible, I'd like to avoid 3rd party libraries, as the system I'm running this on is quite restricted. This must be C or C++ as the existing application is already implemented.

Thanks to **emg-2**'s answer, I managed to make the above mentioned code sample compatible with C++ using the following steps:

Add these headers to both client and server:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
```

In [server.c](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/server.c), change the type of clilen to socklen_t.

```
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno/*, clilen*/;
socklen_t clilen;
```

In [client.c](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c), change the following line:

```
if (connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) { ... }
```

To:

```
if (connect(sockfd,(const sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've used [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/html) in the past.  It's in C, not C++, but the examples are good.  Go directly to [section 6](https://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#client-server-background) for the simple client and server example programs.

Comment: Thanks - I found a sample (http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#simpleserver) but I'm not sure if it's overkill, do I really need all that code?

Comment: @nickbolton2705: Probably, yes. Beej's code has error handling included, which is part of the reason I like it so much. Also note that the server supports multiple concurrent connections, and IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Yeah, this would be great for an elegant solution - I noticed one of the features is serialization, which could be useful to me should I need to implement this properly at some point.

Comment: God bless Beej. His tutorial was my first exposer to socket programming on *NIX when I was little. I don't use c/c++ enough to fully retain everything so when ever I need a refresher I always look to Beej for guidance.

Comment: The link used in this answer is outdated, use [this](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html//index.html#client-server-background) one now.

Answer (score 15):

If the code should be simple, then you probably asking for C example based on traditional BSD sockets. Solutions like `boost::asio` are imho quite complicated when it comes to short and simple "hello world" example.

To compile examples you mentioned you must make simple fixes, because you are compiling under C++ compiler. I'm referring to following files:
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/server.c
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c
from: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

1. Add following includes to both files:

   ```
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <cstring>
   #include <unistd.h>
   ```
2. In [client.c](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c), change the line:

   ```
   if (connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   { ... }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   if (connect(sockfd,(const sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   { ... }
   ```

As you can see in C++ an explicit cast is needed.

Comment: Also, in server.c I had to change the type of clilen to socklen_t, and cast the ouput of sizeof(cli_addr);

Answer (score 5):

try boost::asio lib (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) it have lot examples.

Comment: Are these samples appropriate?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/daytime_server.cpp

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/daytime_client.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Although many year ago, clsocket seems a really nice small cross-platform (Windows, Linux, Mac OSX): https://github.com/DFHack/clsocket

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for:

1) Simple
2) Fork
3) Threads

based server:

http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/server-examples.html