# Is there any way to send http requests from JS by pushing button, to a C++

Tags: javascript, c++, http, tcp

I am currently designing a GUI for a piece of hardware. We want the GUI to be able to be accessed over a browser. The browser would be displaying a map generated from C++ code, but I also need to send some params to the code that generates the map from buttons on the JS front end? Is there anyway to accomplish this. I have done a little research so far and know about web sockets and AJAX, but I am not entirely sure it is what I am looking for. In an ideal world I would be able to just send UDP packets, but my research tells me that is not possible, not is TCP. Is this correct?

Thank's in advance for any help!

Comment: The simplest thing from a browser is to initiate an HTTP request via XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662328/what-is-a-simple-c-or-c-tcp-server-and-client-example

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ code could setup a server that listens for requests. You could use [libhttpserver](https://github.com/etr/libhttpserver), for example. Then, in your JavaScript code, you can use XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch API (for newer browsers) to make an HTTP request to the server, which would then return a new static page (with the generated map embedded into the page).